# Iterative programming - changing class methods name to fit with button names

Tags: c#, class, button, methods, rename

I am very new to c#. I am doing an exercise to create a calculator.
I have renamed the buttons (btnAdd and btnMultiply) and the textbox (textBox1 and textBox2).
When I want to write the methods of the class I have the following code posted just below (I have removed the unused librairies).

I have tried to "rename" the methods by just deleting the reference button_1 and to substitute to btn_add for example. However when I do that I get an error message.

> Error message : the conceptpr cannot deals with the unknown
> 'button1_Click' at line 55. The code in the method
> 'InitializeComponent' is generated by the conceptor and shall not be
> modified manualy. Cancel all modification and try to reopen the
> conceptor.

[image: error message after changing the method name]

Please, may you tell me what is wrong ?
When I follow my professor video instruction, she already gets the method only for the Clear button for example and not all the methods. Moreover her method already has the correct name (for example btnAdd).

Thank you in advance.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Calculette
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

---

EDIT :
I have renamed the button name in the design.cs class but I still get the same error message.

Comment: You should rename them in `designer.cs` class (where event handlers are subscribed) as well

Comment: a) always get the names right before creating the eents. b) you can change the event names while you still can open the designer. c) if, as in your case this is no longer possible you can either revert the name changes (1) or create dummy events with the expected names (2) and then paste the good names into the events pane or (3) go to the form1Designer.cs file and edit the stuff there. (Not for the faint of heart ;-) - I usually go for option 2.

Comment: hello @PavelAnikhouski thank you very much for your feedback. I have renamed it in the designer.cs class but then I get the same error message.

Comment: I have deleted the 'solution' and I will go back to work on it. @TaW our professor is modifying the name of the object in the properties (that is what I did before) and then she had all the methods with the correct name. Is it correct to proceed like that ?

Comment: Don't modify any source files that are auto-generated. Your changes will get nuked at some point.

Comment: Hello @3Dave yes you are right. Well that is an exercise, I have started using such tools. I had to delete the solution. I have created a new one and just had one button to test. By changing the name in properties and then clicking on code the method name appears. I think I did a mistake because I didn't understand why there were 'click' on the method, so I removed it and rewrite it. I think the program didn't understand what I was doing. I will continue tomorrow afternoon. Thank you all for your comments and help.

Comment: It gets easier. We've all been there at some point.

Comment: _our professor is modifying the name of the object in the properties (that is what I did before) and then she had all the methods with the correct name._ Doubtful. Only methods generated __after__ changing the name will pick up the new name. Otherwise other problems would arise, e.g. when several objects are hooked to the same method. Best ask her if she really did that and how.. - Note that the Rename option in the editor will tell you how many occurances it sees and ask which type it should include.

Comment: _I have renamed the button name in the design.cs class but I still get the same error message._ This takes a lot of care; esp you need to search for __all__ occurances of the old name. A Button will be declared but also added to the controls. But what you really were missing are the event handlers, ie the button_click events; best do a search for _oldName_ and then decide for each instance what to do.

Comment: thank you all for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to rename an event handler, like "button1_Click", you need to be aware that the auto-generated code in the designer will be looking for the "button1_click" method, and if you rename it, the designer code cannot find it and will give you the error you are seeing.

**What you can do to avoid this** is to highlight the "button1_Click" method name, right click it, and select the "Rename" option (on my system this is the 3rd option from the top of the menu). Type the new name and hit the "Enter" key on your keyboard. This will rename the method AND will change the code in the designer (and anywhere else it is referenced in the project) so that you will not have this problem.

This will work with ANY variable or method/function name, even the ones you create yourself, not just the auto-generated ones.